# Use jQuery to write width and height attributes to image tags

Tags: jquery, html

Hey folks, I have a page that has a long list of images. These images do not include either the width or height attributes. Unfortunately I don't have the ability to change how the images are coded in the HTML.

The issue is, I am linking to various parts of the page using anchors from other pages. When the page loads it jumps down to that anchor. However, because the browser is not able to correctly determine the height of the images the anchor jumps down further and further as the images start filling in.

So, I was thinking, can jQuery determine the height of the images and append the width and height of the images on all image tags in a specific div? Or, is there a more elegant solution to this issue? Let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

Nothing client side can know what the dimensions of the images are until the images have loaded — by which time the browser will have sized the img element itself.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Is it possible to delay the anchor jump using jQuery? Can jQuery determine when the page is loaded... then jump down to an anchor.. or perhaps to the point of an ID or class?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can write width/height attributes to image tags, but it requires the browser to know their widths and heights - and to know these, the browser must have already loaded enough of each image to get these stats - so not very useful in your case. As you are incapable of changing the HTML or bending the time-space continuum to your will, <strike>there is no solution I know of for your question.</strike>

**But wait, there's hope!**
If you want to scroll to the anchor after the document has loaded, you will need a scrollTo function (see http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo). You MUST use an onload handler to ensure all images are loaded:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // scroll
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the power to edit the HTML nor the ability to bend the time-space continuum to my will. Though, based on my comment to the similar answer below, I wonder if it's possible delay the anchor jump? Not at all elegant, but certainly a little bit better then the mess of an issue this is now.

Comment: Oh, very interesting. I'm going to give this a go. I never knew this plugin existed. I'll post back later and let you know if I was indeed able to bend the time-space continuum. :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you mean by "the anchor jumps down further and further as the images start filling in" But from what i understand you can show a specific part of the pag by including #elementId at the end of you hyperlink.  Correct me if i am wrong so i can edit my answer.

#### Follow-up-1:

Any commands in `$(document).ready(...some code..)` only fire once the page has loaded.

#### Follow-up-2:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var id = window.location.pathname.split("#");
 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top}, 100);
});
```